# How can jumping to another screen when using TabNavigator?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-navigation, react-native-tabnavigator

I use createMaterialTopTabNavigator.

Now I Have a **TouchableOpacity** for go to **Wallet Screen**, and this TouchableOpacity is **in a tab**, And this tab is in my **Home Screen**.
When I click on TouchableOpacity not working and I see no error.

```
<TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={0.8} onPress={() => {
                          this.props.navigation.dispatch(StackActions.reset({
                            index: 0,
                            actions: [
                              NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'Wallet' })
                            ],
                          }))
                        }}>
        <Text>Wallet</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

**Files:**

**Screens Root:** inc/root.js

**Wallet:** inc/wallet/wallet-screen.js

**Home:** inc/home-screen.js

**Tabs Root:** inc/home/tabsShow.js

**Tabs:** inc/home/tabs/men.js   and   inc/home/tabs/women.js

Comment: Are you making use of `react-native-tab-navigator`?

Comment: @10101010 Yes.. React Navigation

Comment: We don't really know how your screens are structured(or what the flow is). Can you please mention your `RouteConfig`'s?

Comment: @10101010 Please check content now..

Comment: Do you have `createStackNavigator` like code? I meant to say those parts of the code related to react-navigation.

Comment: @10101010 I use createStackNavigator In root.js..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188923/discussion-between-10101010-and-alireza).